# Error while reading a text file in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, streamreader

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET MVC. I've multiline Data which I'm storing in a text line and saved that text file in ContentData Folder in my application.
I'm hitting the error that file path is not found like this

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\~\ContentData\WTE.txt'

Please Look at my code and help me how to do this.

This is the View:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "WhatToExpect";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


   <h2></h2>
   @{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

   // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file =  new  
    System.IO.StreamReader(@"~/ContentData/WTE.txt");
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    string notes= line;

    Html.Raw(notes);


    counter++;
    }
    <div id="ChurchImage">
    <img src="../../Images1/redeemer.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>
    file.Close();
    }
```

I've tried replacing @ in the file path. Nothing worked.Please Help me
out.Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the actual path?

Comment: I've placed the text file in a folder named ContentData . That folder is one of folders in my application.The Actual path is "~/ContentData/WTE.txt"

Comment: try using `System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ContentData/WTE.txt"));` and make sure the file is there.

Comment: It work #Waqar Ahmed..Thank You.But I'm able to display only image .Please look at my code and tell me how to display the text?

Comment: I want to display data from text file.Which HTML helper is suitable for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Get your root directoty
var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader( root + @"/ContentData/WTE.txt");
```

**Edit**

Your controller should be like,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader( root + @"/Content/Site.css");
    var fileLines = new List<string>();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        fileLines.Add(line);
    }
    // You can use model, temdata or viewbag to carry your data to view.
    ViewBag.File = fileLines;
    return View();
}
```

And now you can use this `ViewBag.File` in your view to render your file data.

```
@{
    string line;
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.File)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to display data from text file.Which HTML helper is suitable for this ?

Comment: @sujaykodamala, what is the nature of your data? How do you want to use this data in your application? I mean just display each line or do you want to extract each word or something to do any logic?

Comment: I just want to display the data from text file . Does that Helps @Abishek?

Comment: It's a multiline text .

Comment: @sujaykodamala, I think you already done this in your code. right? By using a ``while` loop.

Comment: But I'm not able to display the data

Comment: while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{    
    string notes= line;
    Html.Label(notes);
    counter++;
}....This is what I'm using to display the data

Comment: @sujaykodamala, please have a look at my answer. I have updated it for you.

Comment: @sujaykodamala, could you please give a test data (a line with inverted comma)?

Comment: the bold text is showing boldly.SOrry to ask too many questions.But I want to do it today

Comment: The ? mark issue has been resolved.Boldness is missing Still

Comment: @sujaykodamala, how do you bold a single word in text?

Comment: How about using file with .doc extension?

Comment: @sujaykodamala, I think you can't do that from a text file. If you need to this, please use html tags inside your text file and you can render html tags with in your application.

Comment: @sujaykodamala, for example, for a bold word you can use `<b> word </b>` in your text file.

Comment: the browser consider it as a text if i enclose the bold letter in tags

Comment: It's working foreach (var item in ViewBag.File)
    {
        <p>@Html.Raw(item)</p>
    }

Comment: @sujaykodamala can I get  a up vote? I will not force you, give me a up vote only if my answer helps you.

Comment: Voted Bro...Thanks Bro

Answer (score 1):

Add server mappath to your path.

```
System.IO.StreamReader(@Server.MapPath("~/ContentData/WTE.txt"));
```

Comment: I want to display data from text file.Which HTML helper is suitable for this ?